# UVA 872 - Ordering

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

I am having problem trying to solve the following problem from UVA:

Given a list of variable constraints of the form `A < B`, you are to write a program that prints all orderings of the variables that are consistent with the constraints. For example, given the constraints `A < B` and `A < C` there are two orderings of the variables `A, B` and `C` that are consistent with these constraints: `A B C` and `A C B`.

Input

The input begins with a single positive integer on a line by itself indicating the number of the cases following, each of them as described below. This line is followed by a blank line, and there is also a blank line between two consecutive inputs.
   The input consists of two lines: a list of variables on one line, followed by a list of constraints of the form `A < B` on the next line. Variables and constraints are separated by single spaces.
   All variables are single character, upper-case letters. There will be at least two variables, and no more than 20 variables. There will be at least one constraint, and no more than 50 constraints. There will be no more than 300 orderings consistent with the constraints in a specification.

Output

For each test case, the output must follow the description below. The outputs of two consecutive cases will be separated by a blank line.
   All orderings consistent with the constraints should be printed. Orderings are printed in alphabetical order, one per line. Characters on a line are separated by a space. If no ordering is possible, the output is a single line with the word `NO`.

Sample Input

```
1

A B F G
A<B B<F
```

Sample Output

```
A B F G
A B G F
A G B F
G A B F
```

I tried to use topological sort while using a queue to keep track of the "paths" and print them. However, my code cannot seem to work to my intent. I am not trying to solve the entire question. Rather, I am trying to just print out all combinations first (which I am unable to.).
I am only able to get AFFG from the sample input

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ordering {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numCases = in.nextInt();
        boolean debug = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < numCases; i++) {
            HashMap<Character,ArrayList<Character>> var = new HashMap<Character,ArrayList<Character>>();
            ArrayList<Character> varList;
            ArrayList<String> constr = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Swallow blank lines
            in.nextLine();
            in.nextLine();
            String tmp = in.nextLine().concat(" ").concat(in.nextLine());

            Scanner nextIn = new Scanner(tmp);
            while(nextIn.hasNext()) {
                String next = nextIn.next();
                if(next.length() == 1) {
                    // Read the variables
                    var.put(next.charAt(0),new ArrayList<Character>());
                } else {
                    // Read the constraints
                    constr.add(next);
                }
            }
            varList = new ArrayList<Character>(var.keySet());

            if(debug) {
                System.out.println("Constr: " + constr);
            }

            // Draw graph
            for(String st : constr) {
                var.get(st.charAt(0)).add(st.charAt(2));
            }

            if(debug) {
                System.out.println(var);
            }
            int idx = 0;
            Set<Character> visited = new HashSet<Character>();
            Queue<Character> out = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for(char c : var.keySet()) {
                print(var,var.get(c),varList,idx++,visited,out);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void print(HashMap<Character,ArrayList<Character>> graph,ArrayList<Character> adj,ArrayList<Character> var,int cur,Set<Character> visited,Queue<Character> out) {
        if(out.size() == var.size()) {
            // Print out all complete routes
            String tmp = out.toString();
            System.out.println(new StringBuilder(tmp.substring(1,tmp.length()-1)).reverse());
            return;
        }
        visited.add(var.get(cur));
        for(int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++) {
            if(!visited.contains(var.get(i))) {
                print(graph,graph.get(var.get(i)),var,i,visited,out);
            }
        }
        out.offer(var.get(cur));
        visited.remove(var.get(cur));
    }
}
```

Could someone please advise me on what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: From what you write in your text I think you are on the right track. However, when running the program your obviously doing something completely wrong. The output I get is `A ,F ,G ,F`. As you see you have 2 F's in there which can't possibly be and commas which are not expected. Also you never would output `NO`. From a quick look at your code I could not find the topological sort  anywhere... So, I suggest you step through with debugger and compare what you get with what you expect...

Comment: I am not actually solving the entire problem yet. But I am testing a partial solution to check if I can output all combinations first. I can't understand why my recursion does not work.

Comment: You can use topological sort or create a hasse diagram and then print every possible combination.

Comment: @LanceHAOH: Then please update the question accordingly. What are you *exactly* trying to achieve and what do you *actually* get instead. (don't require the reader to have to guess or read the comments to understand the question)

Comment: @dingalapadum: thanks. I have just updated my question post.

Comment: @dingalapadum: The topological sort is in the print method. The for loop is using a dfs to recurse through all variables. But I can't seem to see where the logic error lies.